# Bootstrap 4 Modal dynamically Show / Hide Footer Buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a modal which I want to be used for multiple tasks -some with just the 'OK' button, others with 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons

I can customise the content using jQuery without problem with the exception of showing / hiding the 'Cancel' button.

```js
$("#btn-modal-cancel").removeClass("d-none");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal-footer">
  <div id=class="col-sm-6 text-right btn-grp">
    <button id="btn-modal-ok" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
            OK
          </button>

    <button id="btn-modal-cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary d-none" data-dismiss="modal">
            Cancel
          </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each button has an ID, However

```js
$("#btn-modal-cancel").removeClass("d-none");
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: you can't use that function cause your button has display none

Comment: Thanks for this, so if I reversed it (which I've tried) to

Comment: ``` $('#btn-modal-cancel').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('d-none');
    console.log(this)
  })```